# C# Array initialization with a ternary operator?

Tags: c#, .net, ternary-operator

They don't seem to work in C#

```
string[] directions = 
      IsSomeValueTrue ? string[]{"RIGHT", "LEFT"} : string[]{"UP", "DOWN"};

string[] directions = 
      IsSomeValueTrue ? new string[]{"RIGHT", "LEFT"} : new string[]{"UP", "DOWN"};
```

What am i missing?

Comment: Now you are missing actually trying to compile your code to see that it runs fine...

Comment: http://ideone.com/rGNjdm

Comment: ok just saw your updated question,if your second statement does not work i got to ask where to be more specific?.....if it does not compile you didnt create the IsSomeValueTrue(very,very remote possibility),or is your values always {"UP", "DOWN"}? if this is the case probably you didnt assign the variable and it defaults to false.

Answer (score 4):

**The shortest one-liner:**

```
var dirs = IsSomeValueTrue ? new[] {"RIGHT", "LEFT"} : new[] {"UP", "DOWN"};
```

Comment: Yeah, first answer (after 4 or 5 other) that is actually good, but what are you answering really? The second version of OP's code compiles fine...

Comment: @BartoszKP, looks like question has been updated...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string[] directions = IsSomeValueTrue ? new string[] {"RIGHT", "LEFT"} : new string[]{"UP", "DOWN"};
```